# How to set icons in title bar in netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, icons, titlebar

I have created an application using netbeans java, I also put a code to set icons in titlebar. It runs without error from netbeans, but when I ran it from external jar file, its not opening, when I tried with cmd it shows null pointer exception error. The code I used to set Icon is
"setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("fw.png")));"

I have imported fw.png to my project.
If any working method is there , please share it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the "fw.png" files stored?

Comment: It is stored along with other jframes under main class.(main package)

Comment: Where would that be, relative to the src folder

Comment: -Freshwater
          -Source Packages
                      -Whole
                             -fw.png

Comment: Have you tried `setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Whole/fw.png")));`?

Comment: Its showing error if I tried the above code. I also have another image to be loaded in the label. It loads correctly. I didnt use any code for that I simply used set icons in label. The problem arises only for setting the icon in title bar. Thanks

Comment: Remember, the path is relative to the package name of the class which is trying to load the resource